# Using javascript to follow links

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am developing a ruby on rails app which as vote up and vote down for products. The code is working the only problem I have is I need votes to be submitted via javascript and I have no idea how to begin this.

Heres my routes

```
resources :products do
  member do
      post :vote_up
      post :vote_down
  end
end
```

heres is my controller file

```
def vote_up
  begin 
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    current_user.vote_exclusively_for(@product)
    @product.score = @product.plusminus
    @product.save
    render :nothing => true, :status => 200
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    render :nothing =>true, :status => 404
  end
end

def vote_down
  begin 
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    current_user.vote_exclusively_against(@product)
    @product.score = @product.plusminus
    @product.save
    render :nothing => true, :status => 200
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    render :nothing =>true, :status => 404
  end
end
```

and here is my view file

```
<td><%= link_to "Vote up", vote_up_product_path(product), :method=>:post %></td>
<td><%= link_to "Vote down", vote_down_product_path(product), :method=>:post %></td>
```

javascript includes

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td><%= link_to "Vote up", vote_up_product_path(product), :method=>:post, :remote => :true %></td>
```

Then you can handle the response attaching an event handler to that link:

```
$(the_link_selector)
  .on('ajax:success', function1) // Executed when server answers with successful code
  .on('ajax:error', function2)   // Executed when server answers with error code
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. Maybe its something with my javascript includes?